# Can I temporarily make all Ruby methods public?

Tags: ruby, debugging, private-methods

I'm reproducing a bug in my Rails console.  I'm interested in what some methods return, but some of them turn out to be private, so in my console I have to write:

```
> my_object.my_method
NoMethodError (private method `my_method' called for #<MyClass:0x0123456789ABCDEF>)
> my_object.send(:my_method)
```

This gets a bit tedious after a while, especially since it's not obvious which are private without drilling through to the class they're defined in.

Is there any way I could temporarily make all methods public?  I don't intend to use it in production, just temporarily in my local console while I'm debugging.

UPDATE: when I say “all methods”, I don’t just mean the ones on `my_object`. I mean literally *all methods* on *every object*.

Comment: I expect Stefan's answer will be, but I haven't had chance yet to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make *all methods* public, this should work:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) do |m|
  m.send(:public, *m.private_instance_methods(false))
end
```

[`ObjectSpace.each_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/ObjectSpace.html#each_object-method) traverses all modules (that includes classes and singleton classes) and makes their (own) [`private_instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#private_instance_methods-method) public.

---

To just make a single object public, you could use:

```
my_object.singleton_class.send(:public, *my_object.private_methods)
```

By changing the singleton class, only the `my_object` instance is affected.

Note that by default, [`private_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#private_methods-method) returns inherited methods too, including many from `Kernel`. You might want to pass `false` to just include the object's own private methods.

Comment: Thanks! I’m afraid my question was ambiguous. When I said “all methods”, I didn’t mean just the ones on `my_object`. I meant _all methods_.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
my_object.class.private_instance_methods.each { |m| my_object.class.send :public, m }
```

might help you shoot a leg, I guess. :) (but the answer above is way better)